# Java dice roll code for review

Tags: java, arrays

I have the below tiny program done in Java using Eclipse. 
It just shows two dice being rolled and what number (eyes?) they show.

Can I do it without the use of casting in the Math.random lines? Or is there a completely different (and better) way of doing this?

I am completely new at programming, so please bear with me (also English isn't my first language.)

```
public class Meyer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] die = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};

        int roll = die.length;

        int random1 = (int) (Math.random() * roll);
        int random2 = (int) (Math.random() * roll);

        String rollDice = die[random1] + " " + die[random2];

        System.out.println("The roll is: " + rollDice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the point of having two arrays with the same data? And even more: perform every step twice? You can extract diceRoll method and just call it two times

Comment: please post questions like this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Following gives you an `int`: Create a random generator object `Random rand = new SecureRandom();`. Get a random integer `rand.nextInt(6);`. The values are `0 <= x < 6`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Where does it say code reviews are off-topic?

Comment: @immibis It´s written in the last part of what topics can i ask here

`If your question is not specifically on-topic for Stack Overflow, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site.`. This leads to the conclusion that it´s not specifically on topic, while codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place

Comment: @KevinEsche That says "questions which are off-topic for SO might be on-topic for other sites". It *does not say* "questions which are on-topic for other sites are off-topic for SO". (In fact, it says nothing about which questions are on-topic for SO)

Comment: @immibis that´s true and i doubt that a tiny example like this would be off topic in any case, while more complex reviews might be fitting a lot better to codereview

Comment: I didn't know about the code review site, just had SO recommended to me. My apologies if I've offended anyone.

Comment: @KevinEsche http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287400/does-being-on-topic-at-another-stack-exchange-site-automatically-make-a-question Moreover, while a question that is not *specifically* on topic for Stack Overflow may be on topic for another Stack Exchange, where does it say that a question that is not *specifically* on topic for Stack Overflow is therefore off topic for Stack Overflow?  With that said, I think this would be a suitable question for [codereview.se].

Comment: @nhgrif [here in the last paragraph](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I don´t know if you could describe this problem as `a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`

Comment: @KevinEsche I didn't say this question was on-topic.  If this question is off-topic for some reason, vote to close it for **that** reason (keeping in mind that being on topic somewhere else, like [codereview.se], isn't something that qualifies an [so] question as off-topic necessarily).  If you think the question would be better suited for another Stack Exchange site and it's not in the list of migration options, the appropriate action is to flag the question for moderator attention and specify that you think it should be migrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally prefer using the `Random` class, and its [`Random#nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) method.

Not only I find it more elegant (and avoids casting), I also find it extremely useful to be able to use the same `Random` object that I created and planted its seed (with the constructor [`Random(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long))), since it makes life much easier when trying to reproduce some unexpected behavior later on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. As stated I'm completely new to programming so haven't fully grasped all the classes of java. Of course I see now that it makes completely sense to have a random class :) Thanks again.